# Collections.js: SortedSet cannot contain incomparable but inequal values: [object Object] and [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I am using Collections.js and I have created an empty SortedSet. The purpose is to hold dictionaries. How can I compare on the bases of specific keys of my dictionary whenever I add a dictionary to my SortedSet. I am not sure how to use `contentCompare(left, right)` member function of Sortedset to achieve this. Thank you.

My code:

```
var SortedSet = require("collections/sorted-set");
var my_set = new SortedSet()
var my_dict = {"value1": 1, "ts", 2020-07-19T08:18:50.206Z }
var my_dict2 = {"value1": 2, "ts", 2021-07-19T08:18:50.206Z }
my_set.add(my_dict)
// runs fine till here
my_set.add(my_dict2)
// throws an error now
```

What I found was inserting second element needs comparison. Looking at the collections.js codebase compareContent() is comparing two dicts which is not possible so how can I can make use of this to overcome.

I wish to compare on the basis of key `ts` which are JS Date objects

Link to the Codebase implementing sortedset as splay tree in collections.js
https://github.com/montagejs/collections/blob/master/sorted-set.js

Link to using compareContent function
. Link to the docs which is not at all helpful please have a look
https://www.collectionsjs.com/method/content-compare

Comment: @Andreas Can you please specify where I am lagging behind in this question in specific. I have done a lot of research in solving this but could not find one.

Comment: @Andreas Please let me know anything helpful related to this question?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the response, I have added more details, please let me know if you have an idea regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [`SortedSet`](https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-set) constructor signatures is:

```
SortedSet(values, equals, compare)
```

You can pass the initial values through the `values` parameter. The `equals` function determines whether two elements in the set are equal. The `compare` function determines the order of the elements.

Applying this to your scenario this would look like:

```
const mySet = new SortedSet(
  [],                                     // start with an empty set
  (a, b) => a.ts == b.ts,                 // check equality based on `ts`
  (a, b) => -(a.ts < b.ts) || a.ts > b.ts // sort based on `ts` in ascending order
);
```

Which would only take the `ts` into account when adding new elements to the set and sort the values based on `ts` in ascending order.

---

Let me explain the line below with a bit more detail:

```
(a, b) => -(a.ts < b.ts) || a.ts > b.ts
```

This line essentially is the same as:

```
(a, b) => {
  if (a.ts < b.ts) return -1; // -1 : a should be before b
  if (a.ts > b.ts) return  1; //  1 : a should be after  b
  return 0;                   //  0 : it doesn't matter
}
```

The expression `a < b` will have a boolean result, but in JavaScript booleans can be used as numbers. `true` has the value `1` and `false` has the value `0`.